# How to convert BigDecimal to Double in spring-data-mongodb framework

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

Spring Data MongoDB mapping by default converts BigDecimal to String. However, I want them to be converted as Double in mongodb. This is required for latter to make queries on this field in mongodb (comparison queries/aggregation queries). 
How can I reigster my own converter (BigDecimalToDouble / DoubleToBigDecimal) to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can add your own converters:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="mappingConverter"/>
    <property name="writeConcern">
        <util:constant static-field="com.mongodb.WriteConcern.FSYNC_SAFE"/>
    </property>
    <property name="writeResultChecking">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter">
    <mongo:custom-converters base-package="com.vladmihalcea.**.mongo.converter"/>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

Now your converters would look like:

```
@Component
public class DoubleToBigDecimalConverter implements Converter<Double, BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convert(Double source) {
        return new BigDecimal(source);
    }
}

@Component
public class BigDecimalToDoubleConverter implements Converter<BigDecimal, Double> {

    @Override
    public Double convert(BigDecimal source) {
        return source.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Before adding converter I got:

```
update test.product query: { _id: 123 } update: { _id: 123, _class: "com.vladmihalcea.mongo.model.Product", name: "Tv", quantity: "10", discount: "12.34", version: 0 } nscanned:0 nupdated:1 upsert:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:49328 50ms
```

After adding converters:

```
update test.product query: { _id: 123 } update: { _id: 123, _class: "com.vladmihalcea.mongo.model.Product", name: "Tv", quantity: "10", discount: 12.34, version: 0 } nscanned:0 nupdated:1 upsert:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:64689 65ms
```

Comment: @Viad BigDecimalToString converter is already available in framework. What I need is BigDecimalToDouble converter. Even If I register this, the framework code is such that it'll always pick BigDecimalToString converter as the default converters are coming before custom converters in lookup.

Comment: @Poorna I amended my response according to your suggestion. I think it's fine to have both BigDecimalToDouble and BigDecimalToString since Spring takes both the sourceType and the targetType when searching for a matching the converter. So if your Java mapping has a BigDecimal field and the Mongo document field is of type double then the BigDecimalToDoubleConverter should be chosen. If all your Mongo documents stored the field as a string than you won't benefit from this converter.

Comment: Habe you tried this? what if ii am inserting first time. How does it know? Look at CustomConversions class. BigDecimal is registered as simple type. Hence will not honor our custom conversion

Comment: I'll give it a try on my GitHub repo and get back to you. The last resort is DbObject converter

Comment: I've tested myself and it works like a charm. Fork my GitHub repo and run [this test](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/vladmihalcea.wordpress.com/blob/master/mongodb-facts/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/mongo/dao/ProductRepositoryIT.java).

Comment: It worked. Iust have done some mistake earlier. Accepting as answer.