# I am unable to Fetch data from mongoDB while whn i using BigDecimal inside query

Tags: java, mongodb

```
     BigDecimal log_max=new BigDecimal(21.11617279052734);
         BigDecimal log_min=new BigDecimal(21.01617279052734);
         BigDecimal lat_max=new BigDecimal(61.43435454343454);
         BigDecimal lat_min=new BigDecimal(61.03435454343454);
         String col_name="latitude";
         String col_name2="longitude";
         List<BasicDBObject> criteria=new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
         BasicDBObject searchQuery1 =new BasicDBObject(col_name, new BasicDBObject("$gte", lat_min).append("$lte",  lat_max));
         criteria.add(searchQuery1);
         BasicDBObject searchQuery2=new BasicDBObject(col_name2, new BasicDBObject("$gte", log_min).append("$lte",  log_max));
         criteria.add(searchQuery2); 

         DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query); 
         while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
                DBObject cursorObj = cursor.next();                 
              LOGGER.info("Collection  successf");  
                Object temp1 = cursorObj.get("longitude");
                BigDecimal longitude = new BigDecimal(temp1.toString());
                System.out.println("longitude ::::"+longitude);
                Object temp2 =cursorObj.get("latitude");
                BigDecimal latitude = new BigDecimal(temp2.toString());
                 LOGGER.info("done getting ");

          }
}
```

I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class java.math.BigDecimal

Does anybody know what will be alernative of BigDecimal....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By going through some of the materials available on the internet, I'll try to provide a concise answer to you question.

First thing, `BigDecimal` is not supported natively by MongoDB so you can't use `BigDecimal` directly. So how to deal with it?

Well, There are alternatives.

1. Convert your `BigDecimal` value to `String` and store in the database. If you are using `spring-data` then it will be taken care of. But storing as `String` doesn't work as expected and *might* give you unexpected results on aggregation queries.
2. If you think that using `Double` will suffice then you can either use `Double` or if you want to use `BigDecimal` then you can write your custom converter in `spring-data-mongodb`, which will convert your `BigDecimal` to `Double` when storing in the database and `Double` to `BigDecimal` when reading from it. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358778/how-to-convert-bigdecimal-to-double-in-spring-data-mongodb-framework/23803256#23803256) answer for an example.
3. You can write your custom type and use it. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255697/sorting-number-values-stored-as-a-bigdecimal-type-with-spring-data-mongodb-in-mo) and [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-763?focusedCommentId=93991&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-93991).

Comment: thax ..... one more help can u help me out how perfrom above same query on robomongo terminal.....

Comment: Well, that's easy. You can try `db.test.find({
    "latitude": {
        "$gte": 61.03,
        "$lte": 61.043
    },
    "longitude": {
        "$gte": 21.01,
        "$lte": 21.11
    }
})`;